# Python socket server loses message

Tags: python, sockets

Python server:

```
import socket
import re
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1
import base64
import struct
from queue import Queue
import threading
import select

def decodea(data):
    buf = data
    payload_start = 2
    if len(buf) < 3:
        return
    b = (buf[0])
    fin = b & 0x80
    opcode = b & 0x0f
    b2 = (buf[1])
    mask = b2 & 0x80
    length = b2 & 0x7f
    if len(buf) < payload_start + 4:
        return
    elif length == 126:
        length, = struct.unpack(">H", buf[2:4])
        payload_start += 2
    elif length == 127:
        length, = struct.unpack(">I", buf[2:6])
        payload_start += 4
    if mask:
        mask_bytes = [(b) for b in buf[payload_start:payload_start + 4]]
        payload_start += 4
    if len(buf) < payload_start + length:
        return
    payload = buf[payload_start:payload_start + length]
    if mask:
        unmasked = [mask_bytes[i % 4] ^ (b)
        for b, i in zip(payload, range(len(payload)))]
        payload = "".join([chr(c) for c in unmasked])
    return [payload.encode('latin-1'), length]

def status(decoded):
    status_ = ''
    status_16 = 0
    if(decoded[1] == 2):
        for c in decoded[0]:
            status_ += (str('%02x' % ord(chr(c))))
        status_16 = int(status_, 16)
    if(status_16 > 0):
            cases = {
                1000: "Normal Closure",
                1001: "Going Away",
                1002: "Protocol error",
                1003: "Unsupported Data",
                1004: "---Reserved----",
                1005: "No Status Rcvd",
                1006: "Abnormal Closure",
                1007: "Invalid frame payload data",
                1008: "Policy Violation",
                1009: "Message Too Big",
                1010: "Mandatory Ext.",
                1011: "Internal Server Error",
                1015: "TLS handshake"
            }
            if(status_16 in cases):
                return status_16
    return 0

def handshake(conn, globals__):
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    key = (re.search('Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r]+', data.decode('utf-8'))
    .groups()[0]
    .strip())
    sha1f = sha1()
    sha1f.update(key.encode('utf-8') + globals__['GUID'].encode('utf-8'))
    response_key = b64encode(sha1f.digest()).decode('utf-8')
    response = '\r\n'.join(globals__['websocket_answer']).format(key=response_key)
    conn.send(response.encode('utf-8'))

def socket_accept__(lock__, globals__):
    lock__.acquire()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((globals__['socket_settings']['HOST'],globals__['socket_settings']['PORT']))
    s.listen(globals__['socket_settings']['LISTEN'])
    globals__['client_list'].append(s)
    lock__.release()
    while True:
        lock__.acquire()
        read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(globals__['client_list'],[],[])
        for sock in read_sockets:
            if(sock == s):
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                handshake(conn, globals__)
                globals__['client_list'].append(conn)
            else:
                for client in globals__['client_list']:
                    try:
                        client.settimeout(0.001)
                        data = client.recv(1024)
                        print(decodea(data)[0].decode('UTF-8'))
                    except(socket.timeout):
                        continue
        lock__.release()

#thead_queue = Queue()
lock_ = threading.Lock()
globals_ = {
    'GUID':'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11',
    'websocket_answer': (
        'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
        'Upgrade: websocket',
        'Connection: Upgrade',
        'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key}\r\n\r\n'
    ),
    'client_list': [],
    'socket_settings': {
        'HOST': '10.10.10.12',
        'PORT': 8999,
        'LISTEN': 200
    },
    'threads':[]
}

globals_['threads'].append(threading.Thread(target=socket_accept__, args=(lock_,globals_)))

globals_['threads'][0].setDaemon(True)

for threadi in globals_['threads']:
    threadi.start()

for threadi in globals_['threads']:
    threadi.join() 

#thread2.join()
```

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var s = new WebSocket('ws://10.10.10.12:8999');
        s.onmessage = function(t){console.log(t); alert(t); };
        s.onopen = function(){
          s.send('hello from client');
          s.send('my name is richard');
        }
        alert('load');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

1. Hello from client

Expected output:

1. hello from client
2. my name is richard

I am sure this is because `client.settimout(0.001)` is not fast enough?

I am pretty lost for words, as i do not know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

No message is being lost due to communication problems, it's just that it is not being decoded. It has nothing to do with `client.settimeout(0.001)`.

When two or more messages from a client arrive close together (in time), *both* messages will be received in a single `data = client.recv(1024)` call.

That means that `data` can contain multiple messages. The `decodea()` function, however, only handles *one* message. Any additional message is completely ignored by the decoder, and that is why you seem to be losing messages.

You can write your decoder to decode and return multiple messages, perhaps changing it to a generator function so that you can `yield` each message in turn. The calling code would then loop over the messages.

Alternatively you could inspect the incoming message by reading just the first few bytes in order to determine the message's length. Then read the remaining bytes from the socket and decode the message. Any additional messages will be decoded during the next iteration.

One thing worth mentioning is that iterating over the client list with

```
for client in globals__['client_list']:
```

seems wrong as each client is just a socket object anyway, and you already know which sockets have data pending: those in the `read_sockets` list. You could write that code like this:

```
while True:
    lock__.acquire()
    read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(globals__['client_list'],[],[])
    for sock in read_sockets:
        if(sock == s):
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            handshake(conn, globals__)
            globals__['client_list'].append(conn)
        else:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            print(decodea(data)[0].decode('UTF-8'))
```

But you still need to figure out how to handle multiple messages arriving together - either in the decoder, or by ensuring that your code reads only one message at a time.

Comment: I will re-read the documentation at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 i was not aware of the merging that was happening. I will modify my decoder to return an array of messages. As for the code modification you suggested, i agree i didn't realize i left the code like that. i will choose this as the answer once i modify it with the solution.